# How can you find change in working capital and capital expenditures without a balance sheet?

Tags: valuation, dcf

I'm working with the following information trying to work through a valuation exercise and I'm absolutely stuck. How can I find ∆WC and CAPX with this information?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide enough information. Yet, if you provide a little more information it might be possible. In theory -- one may recreate a statement for the source and use of funds (i.e., delta balance sheet) from an income statement and cash flow statement. The following adjustments provides a simplified example of the [IFRS balance sheet taxonomy](https://www.wallstreetoasis.com/finance-dictionary/what-is-a-balance-sheet-BS), and it is not significantly different for US GAAP:

```
-(Impairments + Net_Disposals) = NetPPE_New - AdditionsToPPE + DepAmort - NetPPE_Old

AdditionsToPPE - Gross_Disposals = GrossPPE_New - GrossPPE_Old

Accum_Disposals - Impairments = AccumDDA_Old - AccumDDA_New + DepAmort

(AdditionsToPPE - Gross_Disposals) + (Accum_Disposals - Impairments) = (GrossPPE_New - GrossPPE_Old) + (AccumDDA_Old - AccumDDA_New + DepAmort)
```

Note, AdditionsToPPE (above) is roughly analogous to CapEx.

Recreating a delta balance sheet becomes a lot more complicated when you enter the real world. The real world is fraught with nuanced accounting adjustments. One must account also for asset disposals, impairments, write-offs, and M&A activity.

Answer (score 0):

Cap ex can come directly from the CF statement. Looks like you explicitly have it listed as a % of sales. Your change in WC can't be estimated without either corresponding % sales figures of either 1) current asset and current liability accounts or 2) net WC as a % sales. Using #2, you would find the NWC at the end of a year required to support the coming year's sales and calculate the change as the additional investment required to bring the existing WC balance to meet that figure.